# Serilog - Timestamp in log table has timezone, but ignored by SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, serilog

When I cast `TimeStamp` as a `smalldatetime`, T-SQL seems to ignore the timezone, so it appears that +00:00 events happened in the future.

What is the proper way to handle the timezone in a timestamp field in a SQL statement?

Example:

`2021-09-16 13:05:00.3432122 +00:00` returns `2021-09-16 13:05:00` when cast as `smalldatetime`, when it actually happened at `9:05am`.

`2021-09-16 09:05:08.7375111 -04:00` returns the correct time.

```
SELECT TOP(20) 
    Id, TimeStamp, 
    CAST(TimeStamp AS smalldatetime) AS TimeStampx 
FROM 
    SerilogLogs 
WHERE
    Level = 'Error' 
ORDER BY
    Id DESC;
```

Results show the +00:00 timestamps haven't had their hour adjusted when cast as `smalldatetime`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZneR.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that `Timestamp` colum uses the `DATETIMEOFFSET` type. So you may want to use the `SWITCHOFFSET` function before casting it to `SMALLDATETIME`:

```sql
SELECT TOP(20) 
    Id, TimeStamp, 
    CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(TimeStamp, '-04:00') AS smalldatetime) AS TimeStampx 
FROM 
    SerilogLogs 
WHERE
    Level = 'Error' 
ORDER BY
    Id DESC;
```

Comment: AT TIME ZONE is probably a better choice so you don't have to change your query if the source date happens during DST.